# How do I deploy a static website to Netlify that doesn't have any build set?

Tags: html, css, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a website to Netlify but the only problem is that it doesn't have any build settings like npm start, npm build, etc. The website can only be opened on my computer by typing in the folder location in the browser.

How do I deploy such a site to Netlify? I tried looking for answers online but it doesn't give me any.

Comment: Netlify has nothing to do with React

Comment: Is it just a static site? https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/27/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-a-static-site-or-single-page-app/

Comment: @Craicerjack I tried using the instructions in the link but the site either fails to deploy or it couldn't find the page.

Comment: @Craicerjack  After choosing my GitHub repo, it gives me three build settings, Base Directory, Build Command and Publish Directory. What should I type in these three settings

Comment: I dont know, it depends on what you have built. Maybe publish directory

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a static site with no build step, but you want to tie it in with your github repo for CI, then you can put `.` as the `Publish Directory`, and leave the other options blank.

Alternatively, to avoid using Git at all, it is possible to drag and drop the folder containing your website into the "Deploy" tab of your Netlify site settings.

Comment: I tried these two options, but I got a "page not found" error. Does it only work if I have a build step?

Comment: Nope, don't need a build step. Do you have an `index.html` file at the base of the Publish Directory?

Comment: No I don't have any. This is the project I'm trying to deploy https://github.com/AmmanMeb/old-portfolio

Comment: Looks fine to me, you might want to rename `website.html` to `index.html` as that will be more visibly the default homepage, but otherwise it should work?

Comment: @AmmanM have you tried browsing to `https://<appname>.netlify.app/contact.html`?